# Passing multiple/unknown number of variable(s) into JavasScript a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, parameters, arguments

I'm creating a reusable function with multiple/unknown number of variable(s) and one callback.

```
//the number of variable will be dynamic
var a = "this is a.";
var b = "this is b.";

function callback(){
 console.log('callback successful');
}

//totalUp() will be reusable function
function totalUp(allVariables, callback){
 console.log('Here are the complete list: ' + allVariables + '.');
 callback();
}

//how do I pass unknown number of arguments(a and b) into one parameter?
totalUp({a,b},callback);
```

In my code above I'm passing a and b in form of object which doesn't work.

Comment: Use an array instead, and pass it?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking but you could use [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: @CertainPerformance but array need to convert variable(s) to string, which will not be able to capture the values.

Comment: No, arrays do not coerce variables to string automatically...? You can `push` to an array all you want, and the pushed data type won't change, and then you can call `totalUp` with that array

Answer (score 1):

## With ES6

You can use parameter destructuring for it:

```
function test(callback, ...params) {
    console.log(params); // ["a", "b"];
    console.log('Here are the complete list: ' + params.join(", ") + '.');
}

test(callback, "a", "b");
```

## Without ES6

```
function test(params, callback) {
    console.log(params); // ["a", "b"];
    console.log('Here are the complete list: ' + params.join(", ") + '.');
}

test(["a", "b"], callback);
```

Comment: why not keep the singature for non ES6?

Comment: The destructured parameter must be the last one

Comment: `test(callback, ...params)` vs `test(params, callback)`

Comment: As I said above you have to keep the destructed param the last one, otherwise it wouldn't be able to determine what is the last param to map to callback instead of desctructuring it into `...params`

Answer (score 1):

```
let allVars = [
    "this is a.",
    "this is b.",
]
```

You can have some more variables inserted into `allVars` and therefore you can have an unknown number of variables.

When you pass it to the function, you have 2 options.

First one is to pass array and to use it as array

```
function totalUp(allVars, callback){
  let allVariables;
  for (let i = 0; i<allVars.length; i++) {
      allVariables += allVars[i] + ", ";
  }
  console.log('Here are the complete list: ' + allVariables + '.');
  callback();
}
```

As Marvin mentioned, you can also use `.join()` to get the all variables in the array in one string.

```
function totalUp(allVars, callback){
  let allVariables = allVars.join(", ");
  console.log('Here are the complete list: ' + allVariables + '.');
  callback();
}
```

Second one is to pass it as an object

```
let allVars = {
    a: "this is a.",
    b: "this is b."
}
```

Comment: You could use the `.join(", ")` parameter

Comment: @MarvinFischer Thanks for pointing it out, I included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the sinature of the dunction and take first the necessary callback as first parameter and then take the dynamic arguments.

```js
function upTo(cb, ...params) {
    cb(...params);
}

function cb(...params) {
    params.forEach(v => console.log(v));
}

upTo(cb, 1, 2, 3);
```

ES5

```js
function upTo(cb) {
    cb.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

function cb() {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).forEach(function (v) { console.log(v); });
}

upTo(cb, 1, 2, 3);
```